# Virtual robots.txt missing

Tags: 404-error, robots.txt

on every WordPress installation there is a default virtual `robots.txt` file with the following

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

but on my 2 last project `/robots.txt` give me a 404 instead.

- I tried to disable all plugin
- I tried to switch theme with a blank one
- Tried to look on another older project which I updated last week and
  robots.txt is working

This not server related because it work on my local environment with older project

Any idea why ?

Comment: I have no idea why it is missing but you could just upload a robots.txt via ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It just doesn't work when wordpress is in a subfolder.

(robots.txt should be on website root so just create your own if wordpress is in a subfolder)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141656)

Comment: It does answer question. Just try before downvoting... seriously

Comment: wp-includes/functions.php  generates this file dynamically on request, to overite this behavior just create a file manually https://wordpress.org/support/topic/my-wp-site-isnt-showing-robots-txt-file/